# Android: DatePicker - Track change date

Tags: java, android, date, datepicker

I have in my layout DatePicker, and I want that when user change date this date automaticly show in Toast. I used for this `OnDateChangedListener.` 
My `build.gradle` has next params:

```
compileSdkVersion 22
minSdkVersion 14
targetSdkVersion 22
```

Also in styles I write next:

```
<item name="android:datePickerStyle">@android:style/Widget.DatePicker</item>
```

because I want DatePicker in 3 rows (day, month, year) and 3 columns (yestarday, today, tomorrow dates) to change date by swipe up-down.

Here is my code after I initializate DatePicker.

```
datePicker.init(today.get(Calendar.YEAR), today.get(Calendar.MONTH), today.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), new DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onDateChanged");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onDateChanged: " + dayOfMonth, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

I have tested app on Nexus 7 (API 22), and emulator Nexus 5 (API 21) and 5.4 FWVGA API 15.
**Toast doesn't show when I start application and when I try to change date. Why?**

Comment: Everything looks fine, Try cleaning the project or building it. what is `today` here?

Comment: debugging, does  the Toast line run on the dialog closing?

Comment: @UmaKanth I do it but it doesn't help((

Comment: @CptEric I don't use dialog for DatePicker, it in my activity layout

Answer (score 0):

Use the activity as the context and not getApplicationContext(), although both are types of context it can be very fussy on some implementations as it does not know where the toast belongs with the application context.

To use that activity use `MyActivity.this` where you have `getApplicationContext()`, with MyActivity being the name of whatever activity `datePicker` is in.

Also verify onDateChanged is actually in the logs (ie onDateChanged is called)